# "Will have to be resolved without him" and "Will have to resolve without him"

Tags: difference, active-vs-passive

What is the difference between "Will have to be resolved without him" and "Will have to resolve without him" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to make it clearer, I'll add the adjective "this" inside.

> Will have to be resolved without him

becomes

> **This** will have to be resolved without him

and

> Will have to resolve without him

becomes

> We will have to resolve **this** without him

Both have the same meaning, but are just phrased differently. Both show that "a particular group of people" are going to "resolve something" without "someone"

Edit: There is a slight difference, in that the first sentence implies a necessity; it seems more urgent - @Joachim

Comment: so, mine pair is such Interchangeable like yours, right ?)

Comment: the two sentences you provided can be used interchangeably @VanechikSpace

Comment: There is a slight difference, in that the first sentence implies a necessity; it seems more urgent.

Comment: tru thx for the comment @Joachim

Comment: The phrases given in the question are not complete sentences. @DialFrost's suggestion of _This_ gives the first one the necessary subject; you could also use _It, The problem_ etc.